# How to stop Apache redirecting to index.html

Tags: django, apache

I have a Django app that I am serving with Apache using uwsgi.

When I go to 
http://www.myserver.com/

Apache redirects me to 
http://www.myserver.com/index.html/

Which then gives me an error "page not found" (the site does not use an index.html page).

The other URLs work fine, eg http://www.myserver.com/mystuff - is correctly served.

How can I stop Apache redirecting the start site to index.html

Comment: Have you created a .htaccess file in the route directory?  
or you could use Apache's httpd.conf file.

Comment: You need to show your Apache configuration. (Although I'm not sure why you would be using it with uwsgi.)

Comment: Thanks all. The problem was with this line: RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [proxy,last] Dont really know why but I got rid of the $1 and it seems to work. @Daniel - Just out of curiosity why do you mean about uwsgi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 places to look for the problem:

- httpd.conf, .htaccess  - both are apache web server configuration files.
- 301 redirects(if you used any before). If you had any, you won't get to your root url unless you purge browser url routing cache(clearing browser data on chrome doesn't help, for example). How to do that - depends on your browser. To read more on that topic http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/

Comment: Ended up solving this problem by adding **DirectoryIndex disabled** to the the .conf file under the point **<Directory /var/www/>** Had also to clear out the history/browsing data like Alex mentioned.